# Compilation Error While using QuickBox Framework using CocoaPods

Tags: ios, frameworks, quickblox

I downloaded the Quickblox SDK and followed these steps to connect QuickBlox SDK to existing IOS project using this below link :-

http://quickblox.com/developers/IOS-how-to-connect-Quickblox-framework

But Project is not able to build and it is showing compilation error.

i.e **"Quickblox/Quickblox.h file not found"**

Please refer below screenshot and let me know how can i resolve it

[image: Compilation Error]

Also i tried removing the Quickblox framework and added again but it is not working.

Comment: once check Quickblox/Quickblox.h to add any where in custom view controller and check the same error comes or not

Comment: @Anbu its working in appdelegate. I Imported in appdelegate. But what can be the issue in pch file?

Answer (score 1):

This is kinda weird. I just removed the test project and now build Succeeded.